# Bounds on the Twin Prime counting function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

Maybe I'm mistaken, but wouldn't it suffice to show that the twin prime counting function has any kind of strictly increasing lower bound to show that there are infinitely many twin primes?

Comment: You are not mistaken.  This is still a very difficult thing to show, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you have the answers you want.
But the real answer is **no** :
$\pi_2{(x)}>\frac{2x-1}{x}$ for every $x>5$
Clearly, $\frac{2x-1}{x}$ is strictly increasing but this tells us nothing for twin primes.

Answer (score 2):

It would suffice. More precisely, the conjecture is that the twin prime counting function $\pi_2(x)$ has the asymptotics
$$
\pi_2(x)\sim 2C_2 \frac{x}{\log (x) ^2},
$$
for $C_2=0.66016...$

Comment: That's a conjecture, right? If it's proven would that sove the twin primes problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that *would* be sufficient.